# AWS certificate manager detecting wrong domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-certificate-manager

I have an ssl certificate(in GoDaddy) which I key for a domain api.example.com.
I import it into aws using its certification manager. While doing so, I am seeing the domain it is detecting to be example.com, www.example.com

[image]

What exactly am I doing wrong? or there is some issue with aws certificate manager.

Comment: Take your certificate and run the command `openssl x509 -in your_file_name -text -noout`.  What values do you see in the `Subject Alternative Name` field?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it is showing 
DNS:example.com, DNS:www.example.com

But why???

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot I found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I called GoDaddy support and found that by default it picks domain name I own. So while rekeying it is required to mention domain name explicitly.

Steps to do that are as following:

1. Expand **Change the site that your certificate protects** section by clicking on it. Uncheck the box **Change to a hosted domain**. It should look like below
   [image]
2. Save and submit, wait it until it generates certificate.
3. Download certificate and check the **Subject Alternative Name:** fields by using the command.

   ```
   openssl x509 -in certificateName.crt -text -noout
   ```